# why brew showing multiple instances in mac?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

am trying to install packages using homebrew but everything gets installed multiple times, then i could see brew have multiple instances, any chance we can avoid that ?

```
which -a brew

/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

here is the bash profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/awscli@1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/bin:$PATH"

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH="/usr/local/bin/python3:$PATH"

 export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
 1.8.jdk/Contents/Home"
export SONAR_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/sonar- 
scanner/4.8.0.2856/libexec
export SONAR=$SONAR_HOME/bin export PATH=$SONAR:$PATH
export PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: ah, I got it, I removed multiple declarations. removed now. Thank you

Comment: I have removed multiple brew references /opt/homebrew/bin from .zshrc. so its worked

Answer (score 1):

Multiple references to `/opt/homebrew/bin` when defining PATH in .zshrc file created multiple instances. Can be solved by removing that.

Comment: The question doesn't contain any multiple references. Where were they? Add come clarity to the answer and mark it as accepted.